# Relation between real forms of Lie algebras and root systems on pseudoeuclidean vector spaces

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, root-systems

This might be trivial but I cannot see it clearly.

Simple complex Lie algebras are fully classified by the root systems arising from the Cartan subalgebra for which the Euclidean norm is the Cartan-Killing metric.

A real form $\mathfrak{g}_{R}$ of a complex Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ is a real Lie algebra such that the complexification is $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{g}_{R}\oplus\textbf{i}\mathfrak{g}_{R}$. Such real forms are classified by the signature of the Cartan-Killing metric.

I then would say that for every signature of the Euclidean space $(p,q)$ one in principle could have a different real form of the Lie algebra. But this clearly doesn't work, e.g., $E_8$ has 3 real forms $E_{8(-248)}$, $E_{8(-24)}$ and $E_{8(-8)}$.

What I'm not seeing and does not work? More broadly, what is the relation (constrains) between real forms of Lie algebras and the signature of the metric of root space

Comment: A real structure needs to do a lot more than commute with the Killing form. It needs to behave well with respect to the actual Lie bracket itself for a start. Indeed I don't think the signature of the Killing form even uniquely identifies a real form in all cases.

Comment: Yes I quite agree, do you have an explicit relation?